# Map JSON response to object without iteration

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have an entity class:

```
public class ChunkItems {
  private String itemId;
  private String status;
//Five more other fields.
}
```

I'm getting a json response like this:

```
{
  "chunkItemStatus": [
     {"101-a":"SUCCESS"},
     {"102-b":"FAIL"},
     {"103-c":"SUCCESS"}
  ]
}
```

In the above JSON array, each JSON object key represents the `itemId` of `ChunkItems` and the value represents the `status` of `ChunkItems`.

I have a list of `ChunkItems` where the `status` field is not valued. I need to update it from this JSON array.

Below is what I have tried which is working fine:

```
void updateStatus(List<ChunkItems> items){
   JSONArray chunkItemResponse = chunkResponse.getJSONArray("chunkItemStatus");
        chunkItemResponse.forEach(
            chunkItem -> {
              String key = ((JSONObject) chunkItem).keys().next();
              String value = ((JSONObject) chunkItem).getString(key);
              ChunkItems obj =
                  items
                      .stream()
                      .filter(item -> key.equals(item.getItemId()))
                      .findAny()
                      .orElseThrow(
                          () ->
                              new NoSuchElementException(
                                  "Item " + key + " is not present in the chunk: "+ items));
              obj.setStatus(value);
}
```

Is there any way where these values can be mapped to the list without iterating or may reduce the complexity?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to use a `HashMap<String, String>`.

You first iterate over your `chunkItemResponse` and put your `itemId` as the `key` and the `status` as the `value` in this new `HashMap`.

Then, after your loop completes, now you loop over your `items` with `.stream().map` and if you find any item whose status is not present, you can directly get that status with `map.get(itemId)`. Then set it and return inside the `.map()`.

This will increase your space complexity but will reduce your time complexity.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I have tried the below way and its working fine. 
```
items = items.stream().map(tempItem -> {
         tempItem.setStsCd(chunkResponseMap.get(tempItem.getItemId()));
         return tempItem;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

```
There is another answer. I'll just compare the memory usage using instrumentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've upvoted it for the one's who are not concerned with the space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Map<String, ChunkItems> idToChunkItems`, then do the following:

```
void updateStatus(List<ChunkItems> items) {
    Map<String, ChunkItems> idToChunkItems = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ChunkItems::getItemId, chunkItems -> chunkItems));
    
    JSONArray chunkItemResponse = chunkResponse.getJSONArray("chunkItemStatus");
    chunkItemResponse.forEach(
            chunkItem -> {
                String key = ((JSONObject) chunkItem).keys().next();
                String value = ((JSONObject) chunkItem).getString(key);

                if (idToChunkItems.containsKey(key)) {
                    ChunkItems obj = idToChunkItems.get(key);
                    obj.setStatus(value);
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("Item " + key + " is not present in the chunk: " + items);
                }
            });
}
```

Output:

```
[
 ChunkItems(itemId=101-a, status=SUCCESS),
 ChunkItems(itemId=102-b, status=FAIL), 
 ChunkItems(itemId=103-c, status=SUCCESS)
]
```

---

Given the *JSON array* has `N` elements and our *items to be updated* are `M` elements, we effectively reduced the time complexity from `O(N*M)` to `O(N+M)`.

If `N = M`, it's `O(N)`.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed response. Let me check the memory usage. Each list may contain from 1000-10000 items and will run in parallel threads. Just don't want to result in OOM. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've upvoted it for the one's who are not concerned with the space complexity.